# When should a verb be conjugated irregularly in the preterite?

Tags: verbos, conjugación

In class, I have been learning about the preterite tense(past tense). Some conjugations include:

> bailar --> bailé(yo form), bailaste(tú form), etc.

Some conjugations are weird...

> ser --> fui(yo form), fuiste(tú form), etc.

When should I conjugate these verbs irregularly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 rules that changes the verb root in the preterite form:

1. The -car, -gar, -zar rule
2. Triple vowel rule
3. Pancake rule

> The -car, -gar, -zar Rule ***(YO FORM ONLY)***

So this rule is pretty straight forward. If a verb ends in -car, -gar, **or** -zar *(in the infinitive)* then you drop the -car, -gar, or zar. After you drop it, you add -gué, -qué, **or** -cé **(REMEMBER THIS IS ONLY IN THE YO FORM)**.
Example of this:
*llegar -->llegué(yo form)*

> Triple Vowel Rule **(-ER AND -IR VERBS ONLY)**

The Triple Vowel Rule only refers to the *él/ella/Ud* **and** the *ellos/ellas/Uds.* forms. Some verbs have a **double vowel** in the last 3 letters of the word. Examples: *leer & caer*. When you have a double vowel(-er and -ir verb), conjugating(*él/ella/Ud* **and** *ellos/ellas/Uds.*) in the preterite becomes more complicated. Normally leer would conjugate to *leió* in the él form. This creates a **triple vowel**. To counteract this, exchange the *i* for a *y*. *leió --> leyó.* Another example: *Caer* --> *cayó*.

> The Pancake Rule **(-IR VERBS IN THE ÉL, ELLA, UD. AND ELLOS, ELLAS, UDS. FORMS ONLY)**

This rule is more complicated and requires the verb to fulfill 2 requirements. The verb needs to:

1. MUST Be a [Boot verb](https://www.lawlessspanish.com/grammar/verbs/stem-changing-verbs/) **IN THE PRESENT FORM**
2. Be a -ir verb

If only one vowel is changed (**In the present form**), you keep that vowel in the preterite. Example: in the [pedir](https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/pedir) conjugation, the él/ella/ud & ellos/ellas/uds both keep the vowel "i" (its underlined in red).

If two vowels are changed (**In the present form**), you keep the first vowel in the preterite. Example: in the [dormir](https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/dormir) conjugation, the él/ella/ud & ellos/ellas/uds both drop the second vowel, and keep the first one(underlined in red).